# DTS Package unable to edit parameters

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, dts

I have a DTS package where I am getting a very odd problem.

If I open the solution, when I look at a package, I can view and edit the parameter list.

If I open the same file, just as a standalone file, then although I can see everything else. The parameter list comes back blank.

Does anyone have a solution?

Some extra information as per request.

If I open the file directly within Visual Studio (2012 in this case) and view the parameter list, I get the following:

[image]

When I open the same file as part of a project, I get the following:

[image]

No errors are reported, but when I open the file stand alone I can no longer see the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems you want to edit the design time values of a package's parameters outside of the context of an SSIS project. As noted with your screen shots, if you open an SSIS package that has package parameters in it, they are not displayed. You get the same behavior if you click on the Parameter tab for an SSIS project that is using the classic Package deployment model.

This appears to be by design but you're welcome to open a Connect item to see if the product team will change this behaviour.

In the mean time, I see two approaches. The first is to hand edit the XML. Right click, view code and you'll find a section like the following. Change the value of your `ParameterValue` section and you'll be right as rain. The most important thing of course is that prior to mucking about with XML is to ensure you have a known, safe, recoverable version of the package - preferably in some sort of version control.

```
  <DTS:PackageParameters>
    <DTS:PackageParameter
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DataType="3"
      DTS:DTSID="{C6988EC3-F273-4889-83B8-02A4AC8F6E9A}"
      DTS:ObjectName="MyParameter">
      <DTS:Property
        DTS:DataType="3"
        DTS:Name="ParameterValue">0</DTS:Property>
    </DTS:PackageParameter>
  </DTS:PackageParameters>
```

A different approach, and one that I would likely employ is to not care about what the package has as a value on disk. Instead, I'd focus on the value after deployment.

Consider the following code, it applies a configuration in the SSISDB that ensures the value of MyParamter is always 1. At rest, the value is 0 but by applying a configuration, I know that when this package runs in the catalog, it's going to use the configured value and not the design-time value. This approach is also generally going to be more accepted in places that are subject to change controls like SOX/SAS70/HIPPA/PCI etc

```
DECLARE @var int = 1;
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_object_parameter_value
    @object_type = 30
,   @parameter_name = N'MyParameter'
,   @object_name = N'Package.dtsx'
,   @folder_name = N'Deploy'
,   @project_name = N'SO_ProjectDeploymentModel'
,   @value_type = V
,   @parameter_value = @var;
```